# Camera2 API - jpeg capture file size too big

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm using Camera2 api to do a still image capture and save it to a jpeg file. The problem is that the size of the file is always >900kb, even if I set the image dimensions to the smallest available and put jpeg quality low.

This is how I'm saving the file in the `ImageAvailableListener`. It's a xamarin project so code is in c#.

```
image = reader.AcquireLatestImage();
ByteBuffer buffer = image.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Remaining()];
buffer.Get(bytes);
output = new FileOutputStream(File);
output.Write(bytes);
output.Close();
```

The file should be ~20kb, so why can't I get file sizes lower than 900kb?

Answer (score 2):

You can also reduce the capture image quality

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_THUMBNAIL_QUALITY, (byte) 70); // add this line and set your own quality
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be ```CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY``` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Needed to create a bitmap to apply compression:

```
image = reader.AcquireLatestImage();
ByteBuffer buffer = image.GetPlanes()[0].Buffer;
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Remaining()];
buffer.Get(bytes);

// need to get the bitmap in order to compress
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 85, stream);

    Save(stream.GetBuffer());
}
```